# Can CloudKit host and stream audio?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, icloud, cloudkit

I would like to upload .mp3 audio files to the public CloudKit container for my app. I would like users to be able to stream these audio files reliably within my app.

I'm currently trying to use `AVPlayerItem(url: url)` to stream the audio. This works when you have a URL.

As far as I understand it, you cannot directly get the URLs of files in CloudKit.

Can I use iCloud/CloudKit for Hosting and Streaming audio? Or do I need to go with something like AWS S3?

Comment: It depends on how you set up your system in the Cloud Kit dashboard.

Comment: @ElTomato vague responses can point users in the right direction, but in depth answers are preferred.

Comment: If you have details on how to configure CloudKit to do this, that would be a helpful response.

Comment: Or just if it is good practice in general. I'm really looking for a broad answer like "iCloud is really not setup to do that, you'd be better off going with AWS S3".